# automatic number formatting with ConTeXt

Tags: luatex, context

I would like to have calculated numbers automatically formatted, so that my pupils can easily read long numbers in my presentations. I figured out that `setupunits` combined with units, are quite convenient, but they work only if the digits are already formatted with points, and you can't pass a call to tex.print within this macro, as seen in this MWE

```
\setcharacterspacing[frenchpunctuation]
\mainlanguage[fr]
\language[fr]

\setupunits [method=3,order=reverse]

\starttext
\unit{1.000.333}

\unit{1000333}

{\directlua{tex.print(333*999)}}

\unit{\directlua{tex.print(333*999)}}

\stoptext
```

[image: formatting output]

What I would like is having a fourth line looking like 332 667 (eventually 332.667, which is also correct in French typography).

After a quick search on the web, I found [this lua function](http://lua-users.org/wiki/FormattingNumbers) that could be assigned as a variable and then passed to `units`

```
function comma_value(n) -- credit http://richard.warburton.it
    local left,num,right = string.match(n,'^([^%d]*%d)(%d*)(.-)$')
    return left..(num:reverse():gsub('(%d%d%d)','%1,'):reverse())..right
end
```

The trouble is my lua skills are none. As far as I understand, such a function should be declared in a `\startluacode` `\stopluacode` environment, but even then I still have the issue that

```
\unit{\directlua(comma_value(tex.print(333*999))}
```

does not have any output.

So,

- Is there a way to get this `unit`, `comma_value` and `tex.print` working together?
- How could I tweak the comma_value function to have an French output, something like 332.667 instead of 333,667 (I understand `(num:reverse():gsub('(%d%d%d)','%1.')` should do the job for integers, but what if decimals are involved?)
- Last but not least, I suppose there is already a lua function doing the job in ConTeXt internal. Do you know it?

Comment: You need to call `comma_value` inside `tex.print`: `\directlua{tex.print(comma_value(333*999))}`

Comment: @DG' it is a very good first step: `\directlua{tex.print(comma_value(333*999))}` output is indeed 332,667 but `\unit{\directlua{tex.print(comma_value(333*999))}}`has still no output. How can I turn it to be properly processed by `unit` or, without `\unit`, to have an output like 332.667 even for digits?

Comment: I don't now why, but `\unit` doesn't take the output. But you can call `unit` from lua with `context.unit`. I'll add an example in a minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `\unit` from within lua with `context.unit` and do all the formatting there:

```
\setcharacterspacing[frenchpunctuation]
\mainlanguage[fr]
\language[fr]


\startluacode
userdata = userdata or { }

function userdata.comma_value(n) -- credit http://richard.warburton.it
  local left,num,right = string.match(n,'^([^%d]*%d)(%d*)(.-)$')
  return left..(num:reverse():gsub('(%d%d%d)','%1,'):reverse())..right
end

function userdata.formatted_number(n)
  context.unit(userdata.comma_value(n))
end
\stopluacode

\setupunits [method=3]

\starttext

A formatted number: \directlua{userdata.formatted_number(333.3*999.9)}

\stoptext
```

[image]

You can also make a ConTeXt-command that wraps around your lua-code:

```
\def\formattednumber#1%
  {\directlua{userdata.formatted_number(#1)}}
```

Now you can just use it like this: `\formattednumber{333.3*999.9}`

Comment: This is really great. Could you explain the meaning of `userdata = userdata or { }` and why `tex.print` is not needed?

Comment: `userdata` is the namespace for your own functions, using it is a precaution against accidentally messing with the lua internals. `tex.print` is not needed since `context.unit` already produces the output.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it using `\unit`, you have to expand the call to `\directlua` first.  I'm using [`\cldcontext`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/fca2d946bc4d3ef525c3a2c9016e3b88d6d09812/tex/context/base/mkiv/cldf-ini.mkiv#L56) which is essentially a shortcut for `\directlua{tex.sprint(...)}` (with extra bells and whistles).  To expand `\cldcontext` before `\unit` I use `\expanded`.

```
\setcharacterspacing[frenchpunctuation]
\mainlanguage[fr]
\language[fr]

\setupunits [method=3]

\startluacode
```

```lua
function userdata.comma_value(n) -- credit http://richard.warburton.it
    local left,num,right = string.match(n,'^([^%d]*%d)(%d*)(.-)$')
    return left..(num:reverse():gsub('(%d%d%d)','%1,'):reverse())..right
end
```

```
\stopluacode

\starttext

\expanded{\unit{\cldcontext{userdata.comma_value(333.3*999.9)}}}

\stoptext
```

[image]